# What should i test for this Angularjs Login controller with $http service?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

I'm doing a simple app (yo angular-generator) that make a login through a Auth factory with $http.get(). If success, the "sessionId" value is set in local with $localStorage. Everything works correctly, but i have serious problems with unit-testing. I can't define in my mind what should i test! 
This is my situation.

controllers/logincontrollers.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('LoginCtrl',['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$localStorage', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $localStorage, Auth) {

  Auth.Logout();
  $rootScope.loginSucceeded = false;
  $scope.currentUser = {};

  $scope.login = function () {
    var formData = {
      username: $scope.username,
      password: $scope.password
    };

    Auth.Login(formData).then(function (response) {
      if (response.data.loginSucceeded === true && response.data.sessionId !== null) {
        $scope.currentUser = {username: $scope.username, sessionId: response.data.sessionId};
        $localStorage.currentUser = $scope.currentUser;
        $rootScope.loginSucceeded = true;
        window.location = '/';
      } else {
        $scope.error = 'Invalid credentials';
      }
    }, function (response) {
      $scope.error = 'Connection error';
      console.log(response);
    });
  };

}]);
```

services/auth.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
.constant('baseURL', 'http://localhost:8080')
.factory('Auth',['$http', '$localStorage', 'baseURL', function ($http, $localStorage, baseURL) {

  return {
    Login: function (data) {
      return $http.get(baseURL + '/login', {
        params: data
      });
    },
    Logout: function () {
      delete $localStorage.currentUser;
    }
  };

}]);
```

The server accepts login request only with query params

```
http://localhost:8080/login?username=Test&password=Test
```

And now the crucial point.
This is what i've done in test without errors.

test/spec/logincontroller.js

```
describe('Controller: LoginCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var scope, $httpBackend, LoginCtrl;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$httpBackend_, $controller, Auth) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    LoginCtrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', {
      $scope: scope, Auth: Auth
      // place here mocked dependencies
    });
  }));
  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });


  it('should fetch sessionId', function() {
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/login', {params: {username: "Test", password: "Test"}})
    .respond({"sessionId":"c4b0b46a04b54247ac27f3bd4db289a0","loginSucceeded":true});
    scope.login();
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });

});
```

Every other thing I try to do give me back an error.
Could you help me to understand if this test is good, what should i test? Maybe the form, or the $localStorage or what?
Have you a serious unit-testing manual/resource/best-practice to suggest me?

Thanks in advice.

--- UPDATE ---

```
You can explain why if i do this test:

it('should fetch sessionId', function() {
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/login', {params: {username: "Test", password: "Test"}})
    .respond({sessionId:"c4b0b46a04b54247ac27f3bd4db289a0",loginSucceeded:true});
    scope.login();
    expect(scope.sessionId).toEqual('c4b0b46a04b54247ac27f3bd4db289a0');
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });
```

I got this error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Controller: LoginCtrl should fetch sessionId FAILED
        Expected undefined to equal 'c4b0b46a04b54247ac27f3bd4db289a0'.
        test/spec/controllers/logincontroller.js:44:36
        loaded@http://localhost:8081/context.js:151:17
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 5 of 5 (1 FAILED) (0.008 secs / 0.063 secs)
```

Comment: Your test are good for me. I can suggest to test the Factory instead of the controller

Answer (score 1):

My general rule of thumb regarding testing is this

- Test what you are testing only. If you are testing your Controller test only this
- To this end mock everything else, in your case this would be the auth service.

Test the auth service separately and follow a similar pattern, mock out the $http service and so forth.

So I'd say you're not a million miles away, just split it up into two distinct test suites (files).

---

Mocking wise I tend to use `$provide` to create an empty object and then `spy` on the functions I need and mock the return of the data.  That way you are know exactly what is being called and what data should be returned.

An example of this would be:

```
module(function($provide) {
  $provide.service('Auth', function() {
    this.logIn = jasmine.createSpy('logIn').andCallFake(function(params) {
      //a fake implementation
    });
    this.logOut = jasmine.createSpy('logOut').andCallFake(function(params) {
      //a fake implementation
    });
  });
});
```

The beauty of this is that you can then assert / expect the function has been called like so

```
expect(Auth.LogIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

You can also do more advanced things like check that it was called with specific parameters.  There is lots of easily accessible content about this you can google now you know what to look for.

Note the code above was hand written so there may be slight errors. This is a [good website](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) showing what Jasmine v2 can do.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Could you be more explicit for "mock everything else". In my case how should i practically mock the Auth service? Could you show me an example. Thanks